# Do we want a community blog?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, community-blog

One of the things that can help this site grow, is have [a community blog](http://blog.stackexchange.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/).  My question is would we like a community blog? I myself would agree that this site can use a blog.  What do you guys think?  what should the topic/scope and purpose be?

A few suggestions on what the topic should be is:

1. **Da'wah**, we can make posts to do Da'wah.  Perhaps we can invite/find a ***knowledgeable***  **scholar** who would be willing to help with posts.  And I say scholar or any other knowledgeable person, because one requirement for Da'wah is knowledge.  Knowledge to what one is inviting to, knowledge in those whom they are inviting to, knowledge in the ( ***Islamic*** ) ways in inviting, and so on, the list can go on, but the point is, knowledge is important for Da'wah.
2. If we want a blog, the topic can always be about [our site](https://islam.stackexchange.com/), for example we can post about high quality questions and answers, in other words recognizing our high quality content.  We can always post about certain issues on our site, current issues/events, and so on.
3. Our blog can be on a number of topics
4. It can be on comparative religion
5. It can be on one certain topic, like on Ilmul Rijal, or on how to make Da'wah, or it could be on the basics, or it can be on a topic under the sciences of the Quran, etc.

These are only few suggestion, I believe that more can be brought up.

**If you like the idea of a community blog (regardless of whether you will contribute or not), please upvote this questions.**

Comment: Yes, a community blog would be very useful for our site and I would contribute it, I'll think it over and try to answer/comment.

Comment: good idea, good if also I can be any useful

Comment: I can help with the proofreading and editing of posts. I am quite busy with some other stuff these days. Not sure if I will be able to submit **posts** to the blog.

Answer (score 3):

*OK, this answer is for summarizing what we have, and organizing what we should/need. Please help by editing, commenting, or adding new answers.*

### Plan

- Define the Scope. ( ***Done*** )
- Recruit contributors. ( ***In Process*** )
- Prepare 4-5 posts: this will help us plan a schedule if we need it, launch the blog for the first period, and test ourselves and our plan. ( ***Completed -by one user-*** )
- Apply for the blog. < **Completed** >
- Get other tools, like chat room, and Trello, ready. ( ***Completed*** )

### Needs

- Blog coordinator(s) who will organize publishing, coordinate between contributors, manage the blog, and manage other blog-related things in general.
- A chat room for blog-related discussions and fast coordination. ( ***Completed*** )
- A blog title! (***To start out the title can be something like "Islam.SE Blog" it can be changed later on if needed*** )

**What else?** answer or comment to point to more things that we need.

### Contributors

*If you are interested in contributing, please see and answer at [this discussion](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/696/167) which is dedicated for rallying contributors!*

So far, we seem to have those members who are willing to contribute:

- [Al Ummat مجاهد](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/697/167) is interested in contributing to the blog.
- [owari](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/699/167) is interested in contributing to the blog.
- [Imtiaz Mahbub Khan](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8721382#8721382) is interested in contributing to the blog.
- [Hosam Aly](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8715685#8715685) is interested in contributing to the blog.
- [Tamer Shlash](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/698/167) is interested in contributing to the blog.
- [Dynamic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8734409#8734409) is interested in contributing.
- [Najeeb](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/a/709/9) is interested in contributing.
- [Noah](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/do-we-want-a-community-blog?noredirect=1#comment1282_653) is interested, and says he can help in proof reading and editing posts.
- [mtk](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/696/are-you-interested-in-contributing-to-the-blog#comment1280_696) Says can help by providing feedback and suggestion for blog posts others write.
- [Abu Arkaan](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/696/are-you-interested-in-contributing-to-the-blog?cb=1#comment1293_696) Willing to contribute/help as much as cane.

### Scope

*If you have any suggestions, please add and answer or comment in this question so others will be able to discuss what you say!*

Based on what posts we have in this discussion so far, our community blog will include (mostly, but not exclusively):

- **Posts about Islamic Da'wah & Lifestyle**: Posts that are interesting/targeted to either muslims, where they usually talk about how to practically and spiritually apply Islam in your life and how Islam is compatible with modern life, or non-muslims, where they usually talk about Islam in general and how/why good/convincing it or its practices/laws are. These posts are usually starter-level and not academic (although it's not *at all* bad if they were advanced or academic-level).
- **Posts about (comparative) Islamic Knowledge and Islamic sciences**: Posts that talk about topics in any of the Islamic Sciences fields, like for example (and not exclusion): Tafsir, Hadith, Fiqh, 'Aqeedah (Dogma)... etc (the list goes much further). And may compare/discuss this knowledge either to itself (comparing Tafsir books, fiqh schools in a specific issue, sects in a specific dogmatic matter), or to the knowledge of other religions, like comparing what "God" is in Islam and Christianity, or discussing the theory of evolution from an Islamic and non-Islamic point of view. These posts are usually higher in level than the previous type, but still not advances. They usually are writable/readable by non-experts, but expert-level posts are also welcome and encouraged.
- **Posts about the Islamic History**: Posts talk either about history from an Islamic viewpoint (or as told in Islam), like telling how Humanity began or the story of Noah PBUH, or about the history of Islam itself, like telling the story of a famous battle, how a specific sect emerged and died, and the like. I can't really expect a usual level of these posts.
- **Posts about the site, its community, and its trends**: Such posts may talk about the progress of the site, interview one "rank breaking" member, talk about the questions in a frequently used tag and how they relate to each other, the effect of a new world event on the site and its community, and the like.

Comment: Very good, thanks, but it will be also very useful if we can set the rules how to credit the posts to their writers only and/or how to improve or revise a post. Mention that people of different sects might consider a single post simultaneously correct and wrong, so it is important for a writer not to be wrongly credited by all the posts in the blog. A simple suggestion is to open different pages for different sects, but that also might have some disadvantages that I don't know.

Comment: @owari Of course every post will be attributed to its author. Every contributor has an account on the blog and he writes blog posts, revising is only a matter of correction but it never changes who "owns" the post, you can see, for example, the [StackExchange Main Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com), notice how the author of every post is mentioned at the beginning under the title "by <NAME>". But it would really be good if we classified posts according to the sect, and that could easily be done with categories.

Comment: This is looking to be well on track for possibly getting a blog started - I'll do some looking into getting that setup. Curiosity point - anyone have anything written on their own yet?

Comment: @GraceNote We are happy to hear.  As for to what we have written, I currently have 4 posts, I have a 5th one but am unsure of whether I will use it or not.  I do not know if any of the others have there is written yet, I do know that Tamer Shlash and Owari are intending to write some God Willing.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I wouldn't agree to have a community blog for our site, I would *encourage* that!

An important question is that: Does it *have to* be about a specific scope, like Da'wah, or comparative religion, or it can be about more than one scope, all related Islam and Islam.SE? if the latter, then that's great, and in fact I don't see it a problem, also I think #3 in the question implicitly says it can.

- I would agree to have **posts about Da'wah**, but disagree to have them written by people not from the community of the site, it's a *community blog*, which means that it's written by the community of the site in the first place! (still we may have posts written by non-members) I know, we are a fresh, mostly non-academic people, but we don't need to have a 100% quality posts that would convince an extreme atheist in the existence of Allah, **our Da'wah posts can be targeted towards Muslims rather than non-muslims**, this is easier for contributors, more "digestible" for the community and more attractive for Muslims across the web. Of course, high quality posts that discuss high-level, especially dogmatic, topics are really good and I prefer them above most other topics, and they interest muslims and non-muslims both alike, but we shouldn't expect our fresh community to be able to "generate" such high-quality posts.
- I would suggest it to have **posts about several topics in Islam**, specifically I think about the following topics: Tafseer, Hadith, Islamic History, Islamic Sects (comparison may be included), Fiqh and schools of fiqh.
- We may consider having **posts that are** well written and scientifically correct, but still easy and **starter-level**, due to the fact that most non-arabic muslims, who make the majority of the site, need to get introduced to basic things.
- Of course, we should have **posts about the site itself**!

It looks like I'm about to repeat the points the question itself :) But it seems that these are the valid scopes.

An important thing to consider is that we should preserve the **citation-needed** philosophy that we follow in the site and apply it to the blog, no post should lack to citations/references, otherwise we would contradict ourselves.

If it needs bloggers, I'm already a [blogger](http://tamershlashme.wordpress.com) about many things, including some Islamic topics, StackExchange, and other things. Writing a blog post every couple of weeks or month for our community blog wouldn't be hard, in fact it's a pleasure! And in fact I have two posts in my pocket that I intend to blog, one about Suart Al-Israa and another about Islamic History, if we launch a blog, It would be an honor to write them in it!