# Are You Interested in Contributing to the Blog?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, community-blog

Assalamu 'alaikum wa rahmatu Allah wa barakatuh.

We've had a [discussion about having a community blog](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/653/167) (and it's still open), a summary would be:

- A community blog for Islam.SE is a blog written by the community of Islam.SE (us!) and talks about the topic of the site, i.e Islam, and the site itself, i.e Islam.SE
- Our blog posts can be about multiple topics: Da'wah, Islamic Sciences (Tafeer, Hadith, Fiqh), Islamic Lifestyle, Islamic History, Dogma, about the the site and its community... etc.
- Our blog posts can be at any level: Some posts can (should) be starter-level, some intermediate, and some high/advanced level, taking into consideration that the post level doesn't contradict the post correctness.

That was just a summary, you still can change/improve that by joining *[that](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/653/167)* discussion. What *this* meta post intends to do is to ask you for contribution!

**How do I contribute?**

By writing posts about the topics mentioned above. You can contribute as frequently as you want, i.e, you don't have to do it on a regular basis (although that would be nice), neither do you have to write too many posts, you can contribute with a post every, say, week, month, or maybe a two months. That's not a problem; we know: inspiration sometimes let's you down, and that's not a problem, you can contribute when your friendship with your inspiration gets better! In fact contributing to the site by asking and answering is the best way to get inspired.

**I'm interested, what's next?**

Great!  Please vote up this post to show your approval, and if you can just add an answer telling that you are willing to contribute Insha'Allah, we need your answer to tell the SE moderation that we do have contributors to the blog we are asking them to give us. It would also be nice if you tell us what scopes you are interested in writing about, and how often you expect yourself to be contributing, but still you don't have to specify any of those.

Don't be afraid, take it somehow easy, we do not expect you to write professional posts, it's OK if you write "normal" posts, that's what we actually expect and build on.

Comment: I am not a good blog writer. But I'll definitely help with my feedback and suggestion to the blog post other's write.

Comment: Assalamu alaikum... Barak Allahu feekum for seeing me fit to contribute. I am not around on the net much but shall help as much as I can Insha Allah.

Comment: @AbuArkaan nice to hear :)

Answer (score 4):

I want to contribute. But I have no experience of blogging. I want to watch and learn from the seniors here before I start writing myself.

And I can't even decide now on what topic should I write.

Comment: We are happy to hear you want to contribute.  Tamer Shlash is familiar with the software the blog will run on, if we need any help we can ask him Insha'Allah.  Furthermore you may start writing whenever you wish :) we understand that it is hard to decide what topic to right on, but Insha'Allah you find a good one :) if you wish you can always come to the chatroom and discuss with the other topics so that perhaps an idea can come to you, just a suggestion.  :)

Comment: Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 3):

I too am very keen to contribute to the blog. Hmm, but then thinking a little harder, not very sure what topics I could write about. Perhaps we could maintain a list of specific topics that would serve as starting points?

Comment: We are glad to hear you want to contribute.  We know it is kind of hard to come up with topics to write about, you can always come to our [blog chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8205/islam-ses-blog-chatroom) and discuss there.  Tamer shlash is intending to write on Surat Al Israa' and Islamic hostory, I have completed two articles on trying to introduce Uloom Al Quran, Owari (if I am not mistaken) is wanting to write about basics of shia.  Perhaps you would like to write about the basics of Islam?  when we are further into the months of having our blog, we can change formats and

Comment: come up with different formats we can do.  Like the C.SE blog's format was that they have four different writers write on one topic but from different perspectives/views.

Comment: That sounds interesting :) I guess the more the merrier, different perspectives should certainly help! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I would love to contribute, as for the topic there is no certain one fixed, I can write on a number of topics.  As for when I can write, it may differ from time to time, to be safe I can say I can contribute once a week.

Answer (score 2):

I am interested in contributing to the blog!

I like to read/write about Tafseer and Islamic History, so I think most of my contributions will be about these topics, still I may have posts about other things every other time or so.

Not to be very optimistic, I think a post per month is a good starting, and something I would be comfort with and be able to do regularly, still I may be contributing more, but let's just not be very optimistic and assume one post per month on my part.

Also I have a good experience with WordPress, so I may help others if they find any difficulties when they start.

Waiting for the blog to be launched!

Answer (score 2):

A very good idea! Very happy if I can also contribute. My personal interest is specifically the Islamic philosophy and Quran interpretation (تفسیر) and hidden meanings (تأویل), but maybe I can also contribute to other topic as well, God Willing.

God speed