# The idea of establishing a support group over chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

I understand that the main site is [not an appropriate venue](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189/islam-se-not-a-muslim-peer-support-group) for establishing a support group, but what if we invited people who feel they need help over to chat for further discussion?

Questions like this crop up every now and again and I feel like we can do more for these users than just tell them to look elsewhere for help:

[Waswas causing me to lose my faith](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39698/13732)

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with this, be it in the main chat or in a dedicated separate room. The only thing to worry about is that a *lot* of the peer support questions tend to come from brand new users, often as their *only* contribution, who would not be able to participate in chat until they've earned 20 reputation network-wide.

Comment: Do you think it would be ok for the community to give the question 4 upvotes in order to enable chatting for the user? The question can, of course, be closed

Comment: @Zaid I wouldn't recommend it. Upvoting questions that are clearly off-topic really sends a mixed message.

Comment: I agree, though it's painting ourselves into a corner then since we want to help them but can't because they lack  reputation.

Comment: Here's an idea. We could advise such users to earn rep by suggesting edits to existing questions. 10 accepted suggested edits and they're golden. Someone who really needs support ought to be willing to put in some grunt work to help us help them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to play devil's advocate here...

First, while these questions tug at the heart strings, we are unqualified for giving personal advice.  It's dangerous for people to be making declarations on other people's marriages, etc. (despite possessing incomplete information); random people on the internet may have a huge impact on another human being's life.  Personal advice questions are off-topic for good reasons, and users shouldn't be coming to Islam.SE to seek other user's opinions.

Now, users may still be comfortable to accept all this, and maybe we can offload it into a chat room, however... *this is not the goal of StackExchange*.

> Hey, while we're at it we could implement listofx.stackoverflow.com, toolocalized.stackoverflow.com and notarealquestion.stackoverflow.com! All problems solved! – [Andy E](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57383/give-each-site-a-parallel-site-for-polling-recommendations-and-subjective-ish-s#comment135660_57383), 2010

We've tried this with things like the [blog](https://islam.meta.stackexchange.com/q/653/17163).  It sounds like a good idea at first, but instead of working on the questions and answers, we're doing something else.  We should avoid [feature creep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep), and just do one thing, and do it well.

To avoid the heart strings problem, suggesting users visit sites that are actually intended to be support groups seems reasonable.